# Filter for duplicate requests

Tags: python, json, request, aiogram

When I access the API often, I get the same answers!

These requests are duplicated in telegram messages!

How do I filter out the duplicates?

```
def start_data():

    response = requests.get(
        url="http://api...."
        )
    
    result = []

    data = response.json()
    items = data.get("data")
    for i in items:
        id = i.get("id")
        name = i.get("name")
        price = i.get("price")
        
        result.append({
            "id":id,
            "name":name,
            "price":price
            })

    with open("input.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(result, f)
```

My json file:
Key id is unique.

```
[
    {
        "id": "48683035",
        "name": "Cosmos",
        "price": 24.0
    },
    {
        "id": "48683027",
        "name": "Bar",
        "price": 13.0
    } ]
```

My telegram messaging function
Scheduled once every 5 seconds

```
async def scheduled(wait_for): 
    while True: 
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)
        
        start_data()
        users = user_db.get_user()
        
        with open("input.json") as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        for s in users:
            if len(data) >= 1:
                for item in data:
                    send =f'{hbold("ID: ")}{item.get("id")}\n' \
                        f'{hbold("Name: ")}{item.get("name")}\n' \
                        f'{hbold("Price: ")}{item.get("price")}'
                    await bot.send_message(s[1], send)
            else:
                print("None data...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to store existing ids/objects.

```
all_ids = set()
for i in items:
    id = i.get("id")
    if id in all_ids:
        continue
    (...)
    all_ids.add(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did as you said, but after sending the message functiondef start_data(): is called again and I get duplicates again. I mean, because of the frequent API calls, the results are not always updated in time and may be the same as last time!

Comment: You can create your set outside the function start_data so it won't clear and will contain every fetched id anytime. But in such case maybe the server allows you to specify parameter like 'from_time' which fetches only messages newer than? So you could ask every 5 seconds for messages from last 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It all worked out.